# Can one still train a classifier with an unbalanced data set?

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, naive-bayes-classifier, text-classification

I want to train a binary Naive Bayes classifier. The problem is, is that I have an unbalanced set at my disposal, where the ration between the two classes is roughly 2:1 (250 examples from the first class and 100 from the second class).

Assuming that oversampling/undersampling of the data is not an option, would it still be possible to train the classifier with a 2:1 ration of the classes?

Or is this a really bad idea?

Comment: Go ahead and train, I wouldn't call your datasets as highly imbalanced.

Comment: The good news is that class imbalance isn't a problem! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning